# Xcode 6 assets catalog is not showing the new iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode

I have never understand how this assets catalog really works . In the new Xcode6 under my target i am going to `General->app icons and launch images`

There you have `"use assets catalog"` i hit that for both icon and launch images . What happens now is a series of events that i dont understand .

1. He created a new folder in my project, that called , `images.xcassets` , which i already had, so now i have 2 of them -why is that , and should i remove one of them ?

2.Than in the launch images section, its missing the new iPhones , i have only:

> 2 portrait iPhones, 2 portrait iPads, and 2 landscape iPads

So why i dont see the new `iPhone 6 and 6+` , and how can i add them ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i manage to solve it, i just had to remove that new folder , and in the catalog, hit the + button ,on the bottom left, and add a new file for launch images, there i have all the devices needed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have created the project with an older xcode version ? 
You can delete the asset catalog and create a new one, that should have the new icons then.